# When would one want to use a linked library?

Tags: contract-design, library

My understanding is that if a smart contract consumes a library that only has internal functions, then the compiler will **embed** the library into the contract bytecode. At the lowest level, there is no use of DELEGATECALL - a call to an internal function of a library is a simple JUMP statement.

Conversely, if the library does have public/ external functions, the library has to be deployed separately.

At first glance, it seems that most libraries only contain internal functions:

- [OpenZeppelin's SafeMath.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.1.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol)
- [Uniswap v2's Library](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/v1.0.0-beta.0/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol)

What are the best use cases for a linked library?

Comment: Probably common state for several contracts.

Comment: A few years ago we had a large contract that didn't fit the block gas limit at the time (6M gas), so we used libraries to split it into smaller pieces that we were able to deploy. It should have deployed perfectly fine with the current block gas limit of 12M though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusability, see sentence one [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.11/contracts.html#libraries).

> Libraries are similar to contracts, but their purpose is that they are
> deployed only once at a specific address and their code is reused
> using the `DELEGATECALL`.

Although honestly the use of reusable libraries hasn't really taken off, there is at least one project aiming to provide those: https://github.com/modular-network/ethereum-libraries.

Otherwise, external libraries can also help staying below the contract size limit.